# How JS Scope / Closures is Passing Argument

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Can someone explain why in the following function, I am able to pass an argument to a nested function? My understanding is that it has to do something with closures and scope(which I thought I had a decent understanding of), but I can seem to follow how exactly this argument is being passed.

The below function outputs 1,2 respectively. But how is the return statement **doThis()** getting the argument/parameter for "**a**"? I cant figure where/how this is accessed/passed.

```
function doSomething(){
  var b = 1;
  return function doThis(a){
        console.log(b);//1
        console.log(a);//2
  }
}
var exec = doSomething();
exec(2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `doSomething()` returns another function so when you execute

```
var exec = doSomething();
```

You can think of that `exec` as containing the following function

```
function doThis(a){ // <- takes an argument
    console.log(1); // comes from the b argument in the outer scope
    console.log(a); // not set yet
}
```

Thus when you call `exec(2)` you are actually calling `doThis()` with an argument `2` which becomes the value of `a`.

This is a slightly simplified version. To expand on that, the `doSomething()` function is described as *closing over* `doThis()` creating a **closure**. Conversely, the function `doThis()` is *closed over* or *inside a closure*. The closure itself is simply a limited state around the function:

```
function doSomething(){ // --> defines the closure
  var b = 1; // variable only visible within doSomething()
  return function doThis(a){ //<--> function has access to everything in doSomething(). Also defines another closure
        console.log(b); // --> accesses the OUTER scope
        console.log(a); // <-- comes from the INNER scope
  } // <-- end INNER scope
} // --> end OUTER scope
```

When you execute `doSomething()` the returned result still retains access to the scope within it, this is why `doThis()` has access to the value `b` - it's simply reachable for it. It's similar how you can do

```js
var foo = 40;

function bar(value) {
  return foo + value;
}

console.log(bar(2));
```

Only in this instance any other code will have acces to `foo` as it's a global variable, so if you do `foo = 100` in a different function, that will change the output of `bar()`. A closure prevents the code *inside* from being reachable from *outside* the closure.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `var exec = doSomething();`, `exec` is basically writing:

```
 var doSomething = function(a) {
        console.log(b);
        console.log(a);
  }
```

It became its own function. So passing in `2` like so `exec(2)` works like any normal function except that it has the variable `b` available to it because of the closure.